# OneSignal group notification

Tags: php, notifications, onesignal

I created a project on one signal.

I can send to php notification on my phone.

The problem comes when it arrives more than one notification. The new notification replaces the previous notification (not yet read ).

How do you get instead say that Android has 2 unread notifications?

The array can i send:

```
$fields = array(
  'app_id' => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  'included_segments' => array('All'),
  'data' => array("foo" => "bar"),
  'headings' => array("en" => "TEST"),
  'contents' => $content,
  'android_visibility' => '0',
  'priority' => '10',
  'android_group' => '',
  'android_group_message' => array("en" => "$[notif_count] message"),
  'url' => "http://www.google.it"
);
```

Thank you!

Comment: what is `$[notif_count] message` ?

Comment: Hi found it here https://documentation.onesignal.com/v2.0/docs/notifications-create-notification at the step: android_group_message

Comment: ok I think you must escape this use `"\$[notif_count] message"`

Comment: But is right wrire: android_group' => ''?

Comment: I don't understand what you commented, I suggest use `'android_group_message' => array("en" => "\$[notif_count] message"),`

Comment: I have set the same Group Key ma the notification not stacked.. can you help me please?

Comment: @Andreaphp `android_group` won't work with a blank string. Set it to "test" for example. Also try removing "android_group_message" in case it isn't getting encoded correctly in your code.

Comment: I have again try and don't work. I have speak with a onesignal staff and he called to me, android don't stack notification via web push. Is right?

Comment: @Andreaphp Correct, notification stacking only works for Android apps with the OneSignal SDK.

Comment: I can not believe that stacking/grouping works only on Android apps. This is because grouping is part of Push notifications docs: https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/push-channel-properties
And of course this does not work for me as well

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes or escape `$` here if you want to use `$` as character

```
'android_group_message' => array("en" => "\$[notif_count] message"),
```

OR

```
'android_group_message' => array("en" => '$[notif_count] message'),
```

Comment: It's the same, the new notification replace the previus notification.  Is right write: `'android_group' => ''`??

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set value to 'android_group', like this:

```
'android_group' => 'sameGroup'
```